# How do I cancel user serialization, then redirect, with Passport.js?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have an `express` app configured to use `express-session` and `Passport.js`.

When a user logs in I want to, during `passport.serializeUser()`, check if the user is blocked (database call). If the user is blocked, no session should be created and the user should get redirected back to my frontend, which runs on another port.

```
passport.use(new (SteamStrategy as any)({
    returnURL: `${process.env.API_URL}/login/callback`,
    realm: process.env.API_URL,
    apiKey: process.env.STEAM_API_KEY,
}, (identifier: any, profile: any, done: any) => {
    return done(null, profile);
}));

passport.serializeUser(async (userdata: any, done) => {
    const steamAge = userdata._json.timecreated;
    const avatar = userdata.photos[2].value
    const { id: steamId, displayName } = userdata;

    const data = await user.getBySteamIdOrCreate(steamId, { steamId, displayName, avatar, steamAge })

    if ("steamId" in data) {

        // Don't create session if user is blocked
        if (data.isBlocked) {
            // Redirect here somehow
            done("my custom error", null)
            return
        }
        // Create session if not blocked
        done(null, data.steamId);
    } else {
        done(null, false);
    }

});
passport.deserializeUser(async (steamid: string, done) => {
    const data = await user.getBySteamId(steamid)

    if ("steamId" in data!) {
        done(null, data.steamId);
    } else {
        done(null, false);
    }
});
```

If I pass any error to the `done()` function, it just prints out the error on a blank page. But I don't want that and instead redirect the user. I can't use `res.redirect()` here, as I don't have access to a response.

What options do I have?
Has anyone else dealt with something similar?
I couldn't find anything close to my case and the Passport docs were not so helpful either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick. First, return an error using `done()`:

```
passport.serializeUser(async (userdata: any, done) => {
    const steamAge = userdata._json.timecreated;
    const avatar = userdata.photos[2].value
    const { id: steamId, displayName } = userdata;

    const data = await user.getBySteamIdOrCreate(steamId, { steamId, displayName, avatar, steamAge })

    if ("steamId" in data) {

        // Don't login if user is blocked
        if (data.isBlocked) {
            return done({message: "blocked"})
        }
        done(null, data.steamId);
    } else {
        done(null, false);
    }

});
```

And then set up a middleware to catch the error:

```
// Blocked user middleware
app.use(function(err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    if (err.message === "blocked") {
        return res.redirect("http://localhost:3000?blocked=true")
    }
    next(err)
})
```